# Fields not rendered still save

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using custom_object on the `Visualforce Page` and showing the fields based on the user selection on the picklist, even though I hide the fields the value is still saving to the object, how do I not save the fields in the object which is not rendered/hide?

To give you an example here is how I'm not rendering the field based on the condition:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.WeekDay__c}" rendered="{!isTransSelected==true}"  />
```

I'm using the following Save action:

```
public PageReference Save()
{
    try
    {
        system.debug('updating: ' + employeeObj);
        update employeeObj;
    }
    catch (exception e){           
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }
    return null;           
}
```

Or should I explicitly defined what fields needs to be updated?

Comment: A nitpick: you dont need to compare Boolean values to `true` or `false`. You can directly write `rendered="{!isTransSelected}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update specific fields, one option is to create a new copy of the `SObject` that only contains that data.

```
Employee__c record = new Employee__c();
for (SObjectField field : /*yourCollection*/)
{
    if (/*shouldSaveField*/)
    record.put(field, controllerRecord.get(field));
}
// try/catch
```

Comment: one question, I dozens of fields and it will very painful to go each, how about that, if I remove the one I do not want will that work?

Comment: You can't really "unset" the value afaik. You might be able to make the structure that stores which fields to update more scalable so you can loop through fields. @Nick